# getchildren removed for python 3.9

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I read the following:
"Deprecated since version 3.2, will be removed in version 3.9: Use list(elem) or iteration." (https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.getchildren)

My code works for python 3.8 and below :

```
tree = ET.parse("....xml")
root = tree.getroot()
getID= (root.getchildren()[0].attrib['ID'])
```

However, when I try to update it for python 3.9, I am unable to

```
tree = ET.parse("....xml")
root = tree.getroot()
getID= (root.list(elem)[0].attrib['ID'])
```

I get the following errors
`AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'list'`

Comment: Is there a rationale behind removing a core function from a package in the middle of a major version?  What happened to backward compatibility?  What is the sense of suddenly saying this package should not nativley support this function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Use `list(elem)` or iteration" means literally `list(root)`, not `root.list()`. The following will work:

```
getID = list(root)[0].attrib['ID']
```

You can wrap any iterable in a list, and the deprecation note specifically tells you `root` is iterable. Since it's rather inefficient to allocate a list for just one element, you can get the iterator and pull the first element from that:

```
getID = next(iter(root)).attrib['ID']
```

This is a more compact notation for

```
for child in root:
    getID = child.attrib['ID']
    break
```

The major difference is where the error will get raised when there is no child (directly by `next` vs when you try to access the non-existent `getID` variable).

Answer (score 5):

the error is indicating you should write this:

```py
getID = list(root)[0].attrib['ID']
```

invoking `list` iterates over the `root` element giving its children and at the same time converting it to a list which can be indexed